# How to disable screen scaling (not pinch or double-tap zooming) in xamarin webview

Tags: android, angular, xamarin

We are creating an Android application, where we use web-view to render an angular application. When I changed the zoom setting (under accessibility) in any android device, the layout breaks.

I've tried to control this in the angular application by including the meta tag with initial, minimum and maximum scale to 1. But no luck.

is there any possibility of disabling the zoom setting?